# Change navigation menu when bootstrap navigation collapses in Rails 4

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

For my web application, I have a bootstrap navigation menu for my Rails 4 app. Within the navigation when the user is signed in, he sees a dropdown with his username and all of the options to select. This all works fine. My question is that can I have different menu items when the menu collapses.

So instead of just having the dropdown in the menu, is it possible to use different menu items within the navigation? I'm essentially trying to show the items that were in the dropdown on the normal navigation, so that the user doesn't have an extra step to go through when trying to access it when the menu is collapsed.

I've posted my code below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a><%= link_to "Idea", root_path, :class => 'navbar-brand' %></a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <% if user_signed_in? %>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><%= @user.username %><b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><%= link_to 'Manage account', settings_path %></li>
                            <li><%= link_to 'Edit account', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
                            <li><%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
                    </ul>
                <% else %>
                    <li><%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Just use the responsive utilities to show/hide based on device size. Yea, you can have two.